# browsers don't display authorization header in devtools

Tags: http, debugging, browser, header, devtools

Sometimes we need to troubleshoot NTLM or Kerberos configurations.

But browsers (I tried Edge, Firefox, Chrome) don't show the HTTP Authorization header in F12 devtools anymore. This header was shown some in older versions.

I searched all over the devtools. Is there a hidden setting to display the HTTP Authorization header again?
I couldn't find any information about this on the internet.

Edit: in this screenshot you can see that Fiddler displays the "Authorization" header in the request headers. In a freshly installed Chrome the header is not shown.
[image]

Comment: If Edge, Firefox **and** Chrome don't show the Authorization header, then it is most likely that the header isn't sent with the request to begin with. I can see the Authorization header just fine on the latest version of Chrome, on a website of which I know that it uses the header.

Comment: Well, when I use tools like fiddler or wireshark, I do see the Authorization header. But not in the F12 devtools.